# fatal: could not create work tree dir "MagicMirror".: Read-only file system

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, magic-mirror

I recently got into trying to make a smart mirror with a raspberry pi and found an awesome GitHub repo that I wanted to use (https://github.com/MichMich/MagicMirror)

However, when I go to download it to my pi by running

`bash -c "$(curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MichMich/MagicMirror/master/installers/raspberry.sh)"`

I get the error:

`fatal: could not create work tree dir 'MagicMirror'.: Read-only file system`

This comes right after it tells me it successfully downloaded Node.js, then tries to Clone MagicMirror but fails. Any help?

Comment: Please ask in the issues part of the repo forum. I'm sure whatever problem you had may have been fixed now.